# Group by date and count of categorical variable date wise

Tags: date, group-by, count, categorical-data, wise

Date frame having two categorical variable column with date time stamp.

| Date | Time | Va | Vb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2023 | 05:55 | A | B |
| 01-01-2023 | 06:25 | A |  |
| 01-01-2023 | 17:42 |  | B |
| 01-01-2023 | 19:17 | A | B |
| 02-01-2023 | 05:55 | A | B |
| 02-01-2023 | 06:25 | A | B |
| 02-01-2023 | 17:42 | A | B |
| 02-01-2023 | 19:17 | A |  |

To group by the set by date and count Va and Vb for a date.
Expected Result:

|  | Va | Vb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2023 | 3 | 3 |
| 02-01-2023 | 4 | 3 |

Wrote in previous slide

Comment: Is this an SQL question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an SQL database (and those empty values are NULL):

```
Select Date, Count(Va) as Va, Count(Vb) as Vb 
  from sourceTable 
  group by date;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rhh3jEPG)

Comment: No asking for Python code

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
out = df[['Date', 'Va', 'Vb']].groupby('Date').count()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
            Va  Vb
Date              
01-01-2023   3   3
02-01-2023   4   3
```